# Primefaces Watermark on Rich Calendar

Tags: jsf, richfaces, primefaces

I am using JSF 1.2, Richfaces 3.3.1 and I am trying to display a watermark in `<rich:calendar>`.

I thought of using Watermark tag of primefaces `<p:watermark>` and so i have included primefaces1.1.jar in my classpath. It works fine for input text, but when i tried it on Calendar by using forElement of Watermark it didn't work.

Please find the below code snippet, where I used the generated client id in the forElement attribute.

```
<p:watermark forElement = "#includeId:GroupMasterForm:arrDateInputDate input" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
```

Is there any workaround for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

I think the problem is that you try to combine two different component libraries. I am not sure if this works at all.

You could try to use `p:calendar` instead of `rich:calendar` in order to test if this is the cause.

Furthermore, I think your `forElement` content might be a reason. If calendar and watermark are siblings you can simply use the id of the calendar instead of the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{dataModel.date}" id="date"
datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
showApplyButton="false" inputClass="watermark" required="true"/>
<p:watermark forElement=".watermark" value="TT.MM.JJJJ"/>
```

remember to define the p:watermark tag outside of rich:calendar